# ZYNQ ZC702 measurements of current

Tags: power-supply, power, current-measurement, power-electronics, voltage-measurement

I need to measure a current with the osciloscope on a ZYNQ ZC 702 board and I do not know what shunt resistor should I pick. I am not so good at electronics so if some one can help me I would be very glad.
The schematics is attached and I want to measure the current drawn from VCCINT. You can find VCC int at page 40 in the right part of the page upwards. Also down in the left there are R256, R222 and C315 related to this power supply.  Moreover on page 39 in the power controller the power supply enters in pin 64 and 65 and there is also a CS signal PWRCTL1_VCC1A_CS .
Basically I need to measure the current drawn from this power supply by my code, with the osciloscope. Right now I believe R222 is the one but if there is another one as good as that it is better(because right now R222 is missing from the board). Also if you think there is another signal that I need to measure in order to get the current drawn by a circuit powered by this power supply please suggest me.

[ZYNQ ZC702 schematic](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/zc702_zvik/xtp185-zc702-schematic-rev1-1.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R75 is the current sense resistor for VCCINT (0.005 ohms).  It is connected to instrumentation amplifier U46.  U46 has a 4.22K gain resistor for a gain of 1 + 100/4.22 = 25 (from INA333 datasheet).  This means that the output of U46 will be 0.005 * 25 = 0.125 volts per amp through R75.  The bandwidth should be somewhere around 10 kHz.  I'm not sure if there is an easily accessible test point for that signal.  It comes out of U46 on pin 6, then through R252 and into U32.  I would recommend soldering a fine wire onto the U46 side of R252 and connecting your scope probe to that.  R252 is probably a larger target than U46 pin 6.

R222 is part of the voltage feedback for the switching converter.  It's marked DNP on the schematic; you should leave it that way.

Comment: So you are suggesting to put my probe at pin6 of U46 and the ground after the R252 and then I will extract the current as I = Vmeasuered/R252 ? Or I do not see something good? As I know I should use the osciloscope as a voltmeter in parallel with a resistor.

Comment: No. R75 is in parallel with the current flow, but you will only see 5 mV per amp across it, which won't give you much resolution on the scope (generally 5 mV per div is about as low as it goes) and you will probably see a lot of noise. However, U46 is an instrumentation amplifier that amplifies the voltage across R75. So just measure that voltage with the ground lead on ground and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ok that is for the voltage but yet I do not know how to measure the current. Did you suggest that measuring pin 6 voltage will give 0.125 volts/amp so basically 0.125 volts means that there is a 1 A current?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Measure the voltage there and divide by 0.125 to get the current.

Comment: Ok, great and hopefully we can measure the current. Thanks a lot!